# Why does my slick.js slider not work on IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slick.js

I am using slick.js for a slider on my website and it works perfectly on every browser except IE.

I tried adding a meta tag or changing the jQuery version but it still doesn't load the slider.

`Chrome:`

[image: Slider on Chrome]

`IE:`
[image: Slider on IE]

Comment: What the slick.js  and IE browser version? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides,

Comment: I am using IE11, and slick 1.8.1, could you tell me exactly what part of the code you need to see?